# Semantic UI - unobtrusively test form validity

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I have multiple `form` classed `div`s in my page and I'd like to know if there's a method that I can use to unobtrusively test the validity of each `form`? Each `div` with the class of `form` has a `button` (with the class of `ok`) which allows the user to continue through the `form` `div`s. I'd like to disable that `button` on page load to ensure that all relevant data is collected from the `form`s, and only when the `form` is valid allow progression. I've tried adding a function to each form elements `change` which calls semantic's `is valid` but that highlights each and every validity issue.

This JSFiddle illustrates my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/3z1wfjeL/

When the First Name field is clicked into it automatically shows **all** errors on the form - I want the errors to only show when **a** required field has been blurred rather than showing all errors as a result of testing using `is valid`.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete solution but it's a small step towards one.

Use the `onInvalid` and `onValid` callbacks rather than what you are currently doing.

I've [modified your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6d2uoav1/) to demonstrate.

The problem now is if, for example, someone has everything valid up until the last element when you want to enable the `next` button (because until it's blurred it will not be valid or invalid).

Right now, the remainder of this cannot be solved with semantic-ui because it doesn't have a "silent validate" option. See this open issue: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/703. One option would be to use another library to do silent validation but that's really not ideal. You could also contribute a patch to semantic-ui though.

If you're interested, I think I've patched 2.1.8 so that `is valid` runs silently (now it's just a matter of making it get rid of the invalid prompts). See [the gist](https://gist.github.com/jcuenod/4d9f854f0d6a722cde23#file-semantic-2-1-8-silentvalidation-js-L1307). (it's far from perfect and if I have time I'll submit a pull request, search for `silent` and you'll find my changes)

Comment: Thank you @jcuenod! I won't accept it just yet as it's got a few days to go, but I'm thinking the whole `disabled` button thing just won't fly without me messing about and doing my own validation :-( I'll keep on looking and accept your answer when it gets closer to the line. Thanks again!